# Need help with updatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

**My content page**

```
  <asp:updatePanel id="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="true">
         <ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                    blah blah
                </div>
          </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:updatePanel>

    <asp:updatePanel id="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">
         <ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                    yada yada
                </div>
          </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:updatePanel>
```

**Code file** ..The following code is at the end of Submit button click event :-

```
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            Panel2.Visible = true;
```

Now earlier I was using asp:Panel..then it was working fine..like Panel 1 would hide and Panel 2 would show up instead..it was AFTER I changed asp:Panel to asp:updatePanel that things got screwed up...now the Submit button just won't work !!

What's gone wrong suddenly ?? I changed it to updatePanel so the page doesn't refresh..isn't this how we implement this thing ???

```
       <asp:updatePanel id="Panel1" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
          <div>
     <p>
        Type ur name

                <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server">
                </asp:TextBox>
       </p>


        <asp:Button ID="btn" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server" 
        Text="Submit" />
     </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:updatePanel>


   <asp:updatePanel id="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div>
       Thank You!

    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:updatePanel>
```

Comment: "isn't this how we implement this thing " - if you understand it, yes. My guess is your button is not inside the UpdatePanel.

Comment: you cant programmatically "hide" an UpdatePanel like that. because the UpdatePanel is the "container" which is firing the postback, and then you're trying to "hide itself" when it posts back? Doesnt make sense if you think about it. Rethink your solution - what are you attempting to do?

Comment: I just rechecked..it IS inside of updatePanel only

Comment: @user289524 - which one? can you post the full HTML

Comment: @RPM1984: user's gonna type in some txt in the text box and then after submit button is clicked..some msg is to be displayed..so I got my button in one panel and that msg in another panel..how else to implement it if not like this?

Comment: @rpm1984..have added the html

Comment: you can't hide updatePanel ?? IS that so ?

Comment: my suggestion is to before attempting to "throw an update panel in" on code that already works and expecting it to work straight away (common mistake), take some time and read about what you are actually coding. @Andreas Paulsson's answer is a good start.

Comment: think I am confused between asp:Panel and asp:updatePanel..plz help..all I did was replace asp:Panel with asp:updatePanel and also added those content Template tags..I thot the page won't refresh that way when the user clicks on the submit button..what am I doing wrong? plz help..thnx

Comment: @RM1984..erm..I am like ..um I read a bit about a topic then start coding right away then try to resolve errors by googling or asking here ..idk learning by doing practical is more fun to me..I just don't have the patience to read ALL of that first :/ I might be wrong but that's what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `Visible="false"` on an `UpdatePanel`, it won't be rendered to the client at all. Therefore, if you're doing an Ajax postback, the client isn't going to be able to make the invisible UpdatePanel visible, because it just isn't there.

Think of UpdatePanels just as markers, showing which bits of your page you want to update on an Ajax postback. For your scenario, I think the easiest solution would be to use *both* UpdatePanels and Panels. Also, because the two things you're updating (the two Panels) are right next to each other, there's no need for two separate UpdatePanels:

```
<asp:updatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel id="Panel1" Visible="true" runat="server">
      blah blah
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel id="Panel2" Visible="false" runat="server">
      yada yada
    </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:updatePanel>
```

Then in the code-behind, change the `Visible` property on the **`Panel`** controls.

Comment: wait lemme try this right away..I thot this too ie using both panels

Answer (score 2):

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx#S3 , you can read

> Multiple UpdatePanels
>
> A page can host several UpdatePanels. By default, when one UpdatePanel on a page updates, the other UpdatePanels on the page also update. Sometimes that’s what you want, but more often than not, you don’t need every UpdatePanel updating in response to other UpdatePanels.
> You can be selective about which UpdatePanel instances update (and when) by setting the UpdateMode property of each UpdatePanel control on the page to "Conditional." Then, when one UpdatePanel updates and calls a server-side event handler, call UpdatePanel.Update on the other panels you want to update. This reduces the load on the server by reducing the number of controls that render, and it reduces the volume of data in the response because UpdatePanels that don’t update don’t add anything to the response.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know where your Submit button is, but maybe try updating those panels with:

```
Panel1.Update();
Panel2.Update();
```

Comment: This won't work - because the `UpdateMode` and `ChildrenAsTriggers` properties haven't been set, they'll be the defaults, and so both UpdatePanels will already be updating on every Ajax postback. The reason the invisible UpdatePanel isn't updating is because it isn't on the client in the first place.